# rails 4 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

While upgrading rails application from rails3.2 to rails 4. I am getting a issue

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SessionsController#new
>
> Mysql::Error: Field 'session_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT
>   INTO `sessions` (`created_at`, `data`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)

In my sessions table I have session_id field, But I don't know how to set default value.

can u help me to resolve this issue?

my add_sessions_table.rb migration file:

> class AddSessionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
>
> def change
>
> ```
> create_table :sessions do |t|
>   t.string :session_id, :null => false
>   t.text :data
>   t.timestamps
> end
>
> add_index :sessions, :session_id
> add_index :sessions, :updated_at    
> end
> ```
>
> end

my sessions_store.rb file

> MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this code in an initializer,

> ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.attr_accessible :data, :session_id

for more info checkout the [activerecord-session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/issues/6) link